# getting OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application with anaconda and jupyter

Tags: python

I uninstalled anaconda and later reinstalled it. However, when i tried running this code below, i got the error>> OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

```
#make ready useful scientific tools
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

here is the comprehensive errror

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-be09e8eaad65> in <module>
      1 #make ready useful scientific tools
----> 2 import numpy as np
      3 import pandas as pd
      4 import matplotlib as mpl
      5 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
    138 
    139     # Allow distributors to run custom init code
--> 140     from . import _distributor_init
    141 
    142     from . import core

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py in <module>
     24                 # NOTE: would it change behavior to load ALL
     25                 # DLLs at this path vs. the name restriction?
---> 26                 WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
     27                 DLL_filenames.append(filename)
     28     if len(DLL_filenames) > 1:

C:\python\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    354 
    355         if handle is None:
--> 356             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    357         else:
    358             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: Guys, nobody willing to help me out?